# Python3 Tuple_to_LDAPMod(): issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-ldap

Here is my code to add user in LDAP using python3 in virtual enviornment, but getting this error

**('Tuple_to_LDAPMod(): expected a byte string in the list', 'inetOrgPerson')"**

```
import ldap

con = ldap.initialize('ldap://127.0.0.1')
ldap_base = "dc=example,dc=com"

dn = "uid=hasnain,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com"

modlist = {
     "objectClass": ["inetOrgPerson", "posixAccount", "shadowAccount"],
     "uid": ["hasnain"],
     "sn": ["Hasnain"],
     "givenName": ["Muhammad"],
     "mail": ["hasnain@example.com"],
     "cn": ["Muhammad Hasnain"],
     "displayName": ["Muhammad Hasnain"],
     "gecos": ["Muhammad Hasnain"],
     "uidNumber": ["10001"],
     "gidNumber": ["5001"],
     "loginShell": ["/bin/bash"],
     "homeDirectory": ["/home/hasnain"]
}
    
result = con.add_s(dn, ldap.modlist.addModlist(modlist))
```

Would you please help me how I can solve this

Answer (score 3):

The answer is right there in the error message: you need to use byte strings.

Two ways of creating a byte string in Python3 are:

#### 1: Create a string as a byte string from the start

```py
example_bytestring = b"Foo Bar"
```

#### 2: Encode an existing string to get a byte string

```py
example_bytestring = some_string.encode("utf-8")
```

So in your case just do:

```py
modlist = {
     "objectClass": [b"inetOrgPerson", b"posixAccount", b"shadowAccount"],
     "uid": [b"hasnain"],
     "sn": [b"Hasnain"],
     "givenName": [b"Muhammad"],
     "mail": [b"hasnain@example.com"],
     "cn": [b"Muhammad Hasnain"],
     "displayName": [b"Muhammad Hasnain"],
     "gecos": [b"Muhammad Hasnain"],
     "uidNumber": [b"10001"],
     "gidNumber": [b"5001"],
     "loginShell": [b"/bin/bash"],
     "homeDirectory": [b"/home/hasnain"]
}
```

or put this after your modlist to encode all v for v in values to utf-8:

```py
modlist = {key:[v.encode("utf-8") for v in values] for key, values in modlist.items()}
```

This will however fail, if one of the values is already a byte string. If you want to take care of thate use:

```py
modlist = {key:[v.encode("utf-8") if type(v) == str else v for v in values] for key, values in modlist.items()}
```

### More Details

Python uses a unicode string representation. LDAP expects bytes strings, which means you either need to define the strings as byte strings from the start or you need to convert them before using them.

As you can see a standard string has the type `str`:

```py
>>type("foo")
str
```

While a byte string has the type `bytes`:

```py
>>type(b"foo")
bytes
```